# The image does not show up when I run this Python code in Ubuntu

Tags: python, image, ubuntu-13.10

Is there something wrong with this code? It doesn't say there are any errors but the 'img' variable never shows at the end.

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

def main():
    b = 4
    size = 25
    fig_width = size
    fig_height = size

    white_rgb = (255, 255, 255)
    black_rgb = (0, 0, 0)
    img = Image.new("RGB", (fig_width, fig_height), white_rgb)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    for i in range(0, size, 5):
        for j in range(0, size, 5):
            if i % 2 == j % 2:
                draw.rectangle([(j, i), (j + b, i + b)], black_rgb)
    img.show()

main()
```

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 to be precise.

Comment: are you sure you have the 2 imported modules?

Comment: @njzk2 It comes from the Python Imaging Library right? I did the terminal command to install it and it said it was already installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL will try to use the ImageMagick `display` utility or `xv` to display images. If it cannot find either, it will fail silently.  Try installing the `imagemagick` Ubuntu package and then run the script again.

Comment: I downloaded the ImageMagick.tar.gz but I can't figure out how to install it. I don't know if this makes a difference, but I am not using Terminal to run the program. I'm using a free IDE.

Comment: Ubuntu supplies an `imagemagick` package that you can install via the Ubuntu Software Center, or `apt-get install imagemagick` if you prefer.